# How to make "use strict qw(vars)" take effect for $a and $b?

Tags: perl

With `use strict qw(vars)`, I get a compile error about an undeclared variable `$c`:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict qw(vars); print $c; print "OK\n"'
Global symbol "$c" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $c"?) at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

But I'm not getting an error for `$a` and `$b`:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict qw(vars); print $a, $b; print "OK\n"'
OK
```

How can I get the same error for `$a` and `$b` as well? Is it possible to delete these variables?

Comment: The linked answer explains why the `strict` pragma does not apply to `$a` and `$b` . A syntax checker like [`Perl::Critic`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic) can remind you not to use `$a` and `$b` in ordinary contexts.

Comment: @mob Add that to the other question?

Comment: Will do. . . . . .